# Pyspark- Fill an empty strings with a value

Tags: pyspark

Using **Pyspark** i found how to replace nulls (' ') with string, but it fills all the cells of the dataframe with this string between the letters. Maybe the system sees nulls (' ') between the letters of the strings of the non empty cells.

These are the values of the initial dataframe:

```
+-----------------+-----+ 
|CustomerRelStatus|count| 
+-----------------+-----+ 
| Ανοιχτος        |  477| 
| Κλειστος        |   68| 
| 'γνωστο         |  291| 
|                 | 1165| 
+-----------------+-----+
```

After using this:

```
newDf = df.withColumn('CustomerStatus', regexp_replace('CustomerRelStatus', '', '-1000'))
```

it returns:

```
+--------------------+-----+ 
| CustomerRelStatus  |count| 
+--------------------+-----+ 
|-1000Α-1000ν-1000...|  477| 
|-1000Κ-1000λ-1000...|   68| 
|-1000ʼ-1000γ-1000...|  291| 
|               -1000| 1165| 
+--------------------+-----+
```

Is there any other way?

Comment: sorry I'm missing something, your column is called `CustomerRelStatus` but in the first argument of `df.withColumn()` it's called `CustomerStatus`, is this a typo or where does this come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps!

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when

#sample data
df = sc.parallelize([['abc', '123'],
                     ['efg', '456'],
                     ['', '789']]).toDF(('CustomerRelStatus', 'count'))

#replace empty string with 'null' and then impute missing value, OR directly impute it with '-1000' in 'otherwise' condition
df = df.withColumn("CustomerStatus",
                   when(col('CustomerRelStatus') != '', col('CustomerRelStatus')).otherwise(None)).drop('CustomerRelStatus')
df = df.na.fill({'CustomerStatus': '-1000'})
df.show()
```

Output is

```
+-----+--------------+
|count|CustomerStatus|
+-----+--------------+
|  123|           abc|
|  456|           efg|
|  789|         -1000|
+-----+--------------+
```

*Don't forget to let us know if it solved your problem :)*

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a space in the second argument of `regexp_replace` so maybe try this:

```
newDf = df.withColumn('CustomerStatus', regexp_replace('CustomerRelStatus', ' ', '-1000'))
```